# Form resizing OnResize-event

Tags: vba, ms-access

On a form I have a rectangle with the vertical anchor set to both. After every form-resize I need to execute code that depends on the new size of the rectangle.
When I execute the code in the OnResize-event of the form, I only get the size of the rectangle at design-time.

Comment: WIth Anchor set to 'Both', the rectangle only will grow in height. Can you just use the Form_Resize' event to track the 'Me.InsideHeight' property to find the size? If you grab the properties (form and rectangle) at startup, then in the Resize event, you can calculate the rectangle dimension (height).

Comment: You are right: the form.insideheight updates correctly. However: when I open the form in fullscreen the rectangle already has a different size than its height property says. - btw: I edited the question: I dont get the "old" value: I get the value at design-time - and thus the Timer-idea doesn't work either.

Comment: Place 'Debug.Print "Open: InsideHeight: " & Me.InsideHeight' as the first line in a FOrm_Open event, then place 'Debug.Print "Resize: InsideHeight: " & Me.InsideHeight' inside your Form_Resize event.  You can manually add a constant into your code that contains the 'height' of the rectangle at design time.

Comment: Good Idea. That seems like a step in the right direction - however the first two inside heights are the same - although I have a much smaller form thats opened fullscreen -> I never get the small InsideHeight. Of course I could approximate the size with trial and error - but thats not really an option with a form that eventually will be altered...

Comment: OK - now I use an additional rectangle in the right lower corner of the form - anchors set to bottom right - and calculate the difference. Hail Mary and hallelujah to microsoft.

Comment: I assume you use 'DoCmd.Maximize' in some Form event? I put a display in each event, and 'Maximize' in Load event. My design-time InsideHeight= 1785 got: Open , Load 1785, Activate 1785 , Resize 12570. If you still can't get that to work, you can always hide a label at the bottom of the rectangle and reference the position of the label.

Comment: No the maximization is due to the tab-arranged Forms - and the form size varies with the users window size. The reference to the label is more or less what I am doing now (see comment above) - thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no better solution even after 2 months I take it the best way is what I described in the comments above: 
I put a second rectangle at the lower righthand corner of the rectangle in question and calculate the size of the original rectangle as difference (original.width=dummy.left-original.left ...)